# How to Further Group Items in a Column After Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL table named "DATA" as follows:

```
id  plan   mode         cost.     purchaseDate
1.  cd3.   ANNUALLY       34.         2020-05-04
2.  fg45.  QUARTERLY      456.        2021-01-02
```

I'm attempting to return the following 3 columns:
plan, planCount, totalCostPerPlan

I've been working a query to return this and so far it looks like this:

```
SELECT
    plan,
    COUNT(id) as planCount,
    CASE
        WHEN mode = 'ANNUALLY' THEN SUM(cost)
        WHEN mode = 'S/ANNUALLY' THEN SUM(cost * 2)
        WHEN mode = 'QUARTERLY' THEN SUM(cost * 3)
        WHEN mode = 'MONTHLY' THEN SUM(cost * 12)
        ELSE SUM(cost)
    FROM DATA
    WHERE purchaseDate >= *not important*
    GROUP BY plan, mode
    ORDER BY plan ASC
```

It sort of works, however, I get the data only partially grouped as follows:

```
plan.   planCount.     totalCostPerPlan
cd3.        5              *not important*
cd3.        600            *not important*
cd3.        32             *not important*
fg45.       1              *not important*
fg45.       10             *not important*
h100.       7              *not important*
```

(The table is just an example)

How to I further group by plan? I'm trying to obtain the total value for each plan, however, they're shown with a separate row for each mode. Please assist.

Comment: Tip: You can use a [simple `case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than a _searched_ `case`: `case Mode when 'ANNUALLY' then Sum( Cost ) when 'S/ANNUALLY' then Sum( Cost * 2 ) ... else Sum( Cost ) end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you want to put factors into the `sum()` then the `case` is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
SELECT plan, COUNT(id) as planCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN mode = 'ANNUALLY' THEN cost
                WHEN mode = 'S/ANNUALLY' THEN cost * 2
                WHEN mode = 'QUARTERLY' THEN cost * 3
                WHEN mode = 'MONTHLY' THEN cost * 12
                ELSE cost
           END)
FROM DATA
WHERE purchaseDate >= *not important*
GROUP BY plan
ORDER BY plan ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for CROSS APPLY to calculate the new cost for each plan mode. Then, you can go for GROUP BY.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(id int, pplan   varchar(10), mode         varchar(30), cost int,     purchaseDate date)
insert into @table 
values
(1,'cd3' ,  'ANNUALLY'  ,     34  ,       '2020-05-04'),
(2,'fg45',  'QUARTERLY',      456,        '2021-01-02'),
(3,'cd3' ,  'MONTHLY'  ,     12  ,       '2020-05-04'),
(4,'fg45',  'QUARTERLY',      40,        '2021-01-02')


SELECT tt.pplan, tt.mode, count(tt.id) as countOfPlans, sum(t.newcost) as totalCost
FROM @table as tt
CROSS APPLY 
( VALUES( CASE pplan WHEN 'ANNUALLY' THEN cost 
               WHEN 'QUARTERLY' THEN cost * 3
               when 'MONTHLY' THEN cost * 12
               else cost 
               end)) as t(newcost)
group by pplan, mode
```

| pplan | mode | countOfPlans | totalCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cd3 | ANNUALLY | 1 | 34 |
| cd3 | MONTHLY | 1 | 12 |
| fg45 | QUARTERLY | 2 | 496 |

Answer (score 0):

I used your query with few modifications to retrieve the answer.  In your query, Near the case statement there was an error and I corrected that by adding end and column name alias. Then  I removed Order by as I want to use the result in derived table to group by further. You can use temp table or CTE (Common table Expression) to retrieve the data as well.  The answer I added is using Derived table.

```
 DECLARE @table table(id int, [plan]   varchar(10), mode         varchar(30), cost int,     purchaseDate date)
 insert into @table 
 values
  (1,'cd3' ,  'ANNUALLY'  ,     34  ,       '2020-05-04'),
  (2,'fg45',  'QUARTERLY',      456,        '2021-01-02'),
  (3,'cd3' ,  'MONTHLY'  ,     12  ,       '2020-05-04'),
  (4,'fg45',  'QUARTERLY',      40,        '2021-01-02')


  SELECT 
   A.[plan]
 ,SUM(A.[Cost]) AS [Cost]
 FROM
 (
 SELECT
   [plan],
   COUNT(id) as planCount,
   CASE
      WHEN mode = 'ANNUALLY' THEN SUM(cost)
      WHEN mode = 'S/ANNUALLY' THEN SUM(cost * 2)
      WHEN mode = 'QUARTERLY' THEN SUM(cost * 3)
      WHEN mode = 'MONTHLY' THEN SUM(cost * 12)
      ELSE SUM(cost) END As [Cost]
  FROM @table
  WHERE purchaseDate >= '2020-05-04'
  GROUP BY [plan], mode   
 ) AS A

GROUP BY A.[plan]
```

Your final result would be something like this: and you can change the query with your tables.
[image]